# Angular http client with progress

Tags: angular

I’m a bit stuck, originally I had a function to fire a post request and return an observable of my response interface :

```
post(url:string) : Observable<ApiResponseInterface>
{
    return this.httpClient.post(url);

}
```

Now when I add the ability to report progress and monitor events it now want to return Observable

I’m not sure how I can catch the event for the progress and also still return my ApiResponseInterface observable.

I can subscribe to the HttpEvent observable for the progress

```
this.httpClient.post(url,{reportProgress:true, observe: “events”}).subscribe((event:HttpEvent)=>{
    // update progress bar

});
```

This is all good but after it’s finished I want my normal observable to use in the rest of the software. How would I do that ? I assume as a guess there is a way to return my observable once the http request is complete but I’m not sure how in this case.

Comment: What do you mean by progress bar, what that has to do with code on this level?

Comment: It doesn’t, that’s just what I want to do and pick up the upload progress and calc % for a loader, so the loading bar will go up as the event gives progress info then give back the original response observable that was there initially. Or some other way if there is one, I do have an interceptor as well if that helps

Answer (score 1):

Try angular doc solution:

It depends on where you want to handle your progress bar update. But lets say that you want to do that directly in your post method. In this case rxjs tap operator is a good tool to do something with the response before it continue its was to the subscriber.
And using the rxjs last operator returns only the last emitted value which is the complete event in this case.

```js
post() {
  this.http.request(req).pipe(
    tap(event => {
      if (event.type == HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
          // update the progress bar
      }
    }),
    last() // return last (completed) message to caller
  );
}
```

https://angular.io/guide/http#tracking-and-showing-request-progress

Comment: I managed to get it working, similar to what you've done, but i used filter() to move to map() with the HttpEventType.Response so it then returns my ApiResponseInterface observable. Thanks for your help!